# Accidentally replaced notify-osd with xfce-notifyd, how do I fix it?

Tags: notify-osd

The day before yesterday, after an update, Gwibber Notifications got screwed a bit (Once I log in, they appear in bulk, for 2 seconds only while before they used appear one by one and each notification lasted 5 seconds).
Anyway, After the same update, Top Panel Notification dialogs changed their background color from Gray (Ambiance default color) to Whitey very light grey.
I can't spot where in Compiz Settings I can tweak this.
I only can set the transparency values for items like Nautilus, Dialogs, Menus.... But no background stuff.).

Someone has a clue ? How can I set the Top Panel notifiations background color back to Default? First I thought it was only Gwibber, but it applies to any app (Firefox, Banshee....Etc).

Thanks in advance.
[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: I bet you've got an upgraded OS. Because for me it seems like older versions of Gnome packages are still intercepting your ongoing system on Unity.

Comment: Absolutely no. I installed 11.10 as a fresh install. No dist upgrade done! But I guess, it might be causeed by the multiple desktop managers I have installed. I have Gnome-Shell, Lubuntu Desktop, KDE, XFCE and Openbox. Yet, the problem happened just three days ago when I applied some ordinary updates like Apache, Firefox, some python libs.... And there is no conflict at all anywhere. The one change I noticed is the Gwibber thing and the notifications whose background changed from Transparent Gray to Transparent white.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have recently fall into this problem. The other answer didn't help me much. But thanks to the answerer above, I found the package name for that quickly.

I did this to solve my problem:

1. Opening a terminal and executing this command:

   ```
   gksu gedit /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.xfce.xfce4-notifyd.Notifications.service
   ```
2. Then replace the line:

   ```
   Exec=/usr/lib/xfce4/notifyd/xfce4-notifyd
   ```

   with this one:

   ```
   Exec=/usr/lib/notify-osd/notify-osd
   ```

   Or, if on Ubuntu 16.04:

   ```
   Exec=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/notify-osd
   ```
3. Save and exit.

Problem solved.

**As an extra benefit**, I get the nice notify-osd in XFCE too.

Answer (score 6):

Ok Found the problem and fixed it.

After installing **Xubuntu-desktop** along for some testing I did, xfce-notifyd (Xfce notification daemon) replaced **notify-osd** (Gnome Notify Daemon) and probably removed the **ubuntu-desktop metapackage** too.

Uninstalling the package xfce-notifyd , resolved the issue. Now notifications are back to normal.

Thanks for your interest.

[image]

Comment: No, This solution did not help me. I have `ubuntu-desktop` but there is still that notification

Comment: This works in Ubuntu 13.10! Thanks. The previous solution with editing the file did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution to this that doesn't involve editing any files and won't be overwritten by a package upgrade. Just use the following two commands in a shell:

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/share/dbus-1/services
sudo cp /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.Notifications.service /usr/local/share/dbus-1/services
```

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me as well after installing XFCE. It's an old question, but accepted answer did not work for me on Ubuntu 16.04. To solve it, I just needed to remove the package `xfce4-notifyd`.

`sudo apt-get remove xfce4-notifyd`

Please note this will force XFCE environment to use Ubuntu's `notify-osd` library.