# How to change Ubuntu 12.04 Unity volume notification?

Tags: unity, compiz, notification, volume-control

I'm using Unity on Ubuntu 12.04 and when I change the volume, I get a different volume indicator than the stock 12.04 notification. Based on what I've found searching through google, it is the gnome volume indicator. How can I change it back?

Things I have installed that I think may have affected it:

- compizconfig settings manager
- gnome-shell

[image: Volume Notification]

Additionally, the notifications have changed color. I tried [the solution described here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128474/how-to-customize-on-screen-notifications-in-ubuntu-12-04) but it did not have any affect on the notifications whatsoever.

[image: Regular Notification]

Comment: What do you mean by "originally"?. Ubuntu has been using a different notification system from about 2009. It might be possible to change it back, I don't know. Hope it doesn't brake anything.

Comment: By originally, I mean the stock volume notification. The one that appears when you first install Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had installed xubuntu-desktop and the solution to both of these notification problems was to remove xfce4-notify: [solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105377/accidentally-replaced-notifiy-osd-with-xfce-notifyd-how-do-i-fix-it)