# Cannot see the new brightness or sound values when turning the brightness or volume higher or lower, how do I fix this?

Tags: 16.04, unity, sound, brightness

I recently installed an update. After I restarted I noticed that when I lowered the brightness or volume lower or higher, it would not show the new value in the purple box that would previously come. I'm relatively new to Linux but I know quite a few commands (I'm willing to do terminal stuff).

I've tried restarting but that hasn't worked out. I've realized that when I connect to a new wifi network it shows a different panel (that is now white). Is this a "new feature", or something that I can fix?

I also tested out the different Unity theme Radiance sometime back, but I don't think that's the issue.

**Edit:** 
The output of `uname -r`:

```
aparms@aparms-PC:~$ uname -r
4.8.0-36-generic
```

Comment: Can you open the terminal and use `uname -r` and update your question with the output?

Comment: Sure, I put it in above.

Comment: Are you sure you are running 16.04 (which uses Kernel 4.4.0) and not Ubuntu 16.10 (which uses Kernel 4.8.0)?

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.2, according to `lsb_release -a`

Comment: I also noticed that when I play songs the notification has changed from a purple background to a white one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. Apparently when I installed xfce, it came with its own notifications and it replaced the default Ubuntu one. I found the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105377/accidentally-replaced-notify-osd-with-xfce-notifyd-how-do-i-fix-it).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install a custom notify-osd package from https://launchpad.net/~leolik/+archive/ubuntu/leolik

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:leolik/leolik
sudo apt-get update
```